# How does Mining Village's extra effect work in Dominion?

Tags: dominion, dominion-intrigue

Mining Village has the option to trash it *immediately* and gain 2 coins. What exactly is meant by immediately? In other words, if I play a Mining Village what can I do before I must choose whether to trash it or not and gain 2 coins?

I'm interested in whether I can first draw another card (one of Mining Village's effects) and play it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You draw the card, but may not play it prior to fully resolving Mining Village.

Always work from the top down on a card.  For Mining Village you do the following

1. +1 Card
2. +2 Actions
3. Optional - trash Mining Village for +2 coins.

Comment: Please note that +2 Actions does NOT mean "play two more cards."  It merely adds 2 actions that you can use once this card has been fully resolved.